# How to sort array of objects based on a given sorted array containing values with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Using Lodash, how would I sort an array of objects based on a given sorted array containing values?

For example, given:

```
const movies = [
    {
        title: "La La Land",
        genre: "Musical"
    },
    {
        title: "Avengers",
        genre: "Action"
    },
    {
        title: "Chucky",
        genre: "Horror"
    }
]

const titles = [
    "Chucky",
    "La La Land",
    "Avengers"
]
```

How do I get:

```
const sortedMovies = [
    {
        title: "Chucky",
        genre: "Horror"
    },
    {
        title: "La La Land",
        genre: "Musical"
    },
    {
        title: "Avengers",
        genre: "Action"
    }
]
```

which is sorted by the sort order of the movie titles from the `titles` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`titlesByOrder`) from `titles` where the key is the title, and the value is the index from the original array. Then use [`_.sortBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy), and in the callback return the value of the current title from the `titlesByOrder` object:

```js
const movies = [{"title":"La La Land","genre":"Musical"},{"title":"Avengers","genre":"Action"},{"title":"Chucky","genre":"Horror"}]
const titles = ["Chucky","La La Land","Avengers"]

const titlesByOrder = new Map(titles.map((t, i) => [t, i]))

const result = _.sortBy(movies, o => titlesByOrder.get(o.title))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

If the `titles` array contains the titles for all the items in `movies`, and the items titles are unique, you can convert the `movies` array to an object using [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keyBy), and then get an array with the correct order using [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#at):

```js
const movies = [{"title":"La La Land","genre":"Musical"},{"title":"Avengers","genre":"Action"},{"title":"Chucky","genre":"Horror"}]
const titles = ["Chucky","La La Land","Avengers"]

const result = _.at(
  _.keyBy(movies, 'title'),
  titles
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need lodash for this. Please check if below soln is useful or not.

```js
const movies = [
  {
    title: "La La Land",
    genre: "Musical"
  },
  {
    title: "Avengers",
    genre: "Action"
  },
  {
    title: "Chucky",
    genre: "Horror"
  }
];

const titles = ["Chucky", "La La Land", "Avengers"];
const orderMap = titles.reduce((acc, data, index) => {
  acc[data] = titles.length - index;
  return acc;
}, {});
x = movies.sort((x, y) => {
  const orderOfX = titles.length - orderMap[x.title];
  const orderOfY = titles.length - orderMap[y.title];
  return orderOfX - orderOfY;
});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: You can remove the `titles.length - ` from all expressions, and still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check via [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) the index and compare via [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). No need to use lodash for this:

```
const movies = [{"title":"La La Land","genre":"Musical"},{"title":"Avengers","genre":"Action"},{"title":"Chucky","genre":"Horror"}]
const titles = ["Chucky","La La Land","Avengers"]

let result = movies.sort((a,b) => titles.indexOf(a.title) - titles.indexOf(b.title))

console.log(result)
```

Unless you are dealing with hundreds of thousands of entries in those arrays performance should not be an issue. If however you need a performant one you can do it via reducing to a simple `key/value` pair where your key is the `string` and the value the `index in the array`:

```js
const movies = [{"title":"La La Land","genre":"Musical"},{"title":"Avengers","genre":"Action"},{"title":"Chucky","genre":"Horror"}]
const titles = ["Chucky","La La Land","Avengers"]
  .reduce((acc,c,i) => (acc[c] = i, acc), {}) // reduce to a key/value pairs

let result = movies.sort((a,b) => titles[a.title] - titles[b.title]) // sort by index

console.log(result)
```